# Facebook username is unique?

Tags: facebook

Is it correct that every Facebook username is unique?

E.g. http://graph.facebook.com/jacobsome

it only returns one record where we can only get one username from json.

```
{
   "id": "625747405",
   "name": "Jacob Verghese",
   "first_name": "Jacob",
   "last_name": "Verghese",
   "username": "Jacobsome",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_GB"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Facebook usernames **are** unique. It has to be because as you said, there is a specific URL for each user.

Users having the same username would conflict with each other.

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook username is unique, **BUT** it may be changed by the user, although just once. If you intend to retrieve information from Facebook using an unique and immutable identifier you should use either **(u)id** or **third_party_uid**.

The field used to identify an user is named **id** in the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) and **uid** (from the [user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/)) in the FQL API. **third_party_id** is an [unique identifier meant to be used when sharing user information with third parties](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/431/) without exposing the real user id.